# How to find out the commands for system settings apps

Tags: gnome, gnome3

I have a distro with Gnome 3. I can get to the Keyboard "app" from system settings. How can I open directly the Keyboard configuration app using a terminal ?

Is there a list with all of this ?

Answer (score 2):

To open the system settings app, itself, just invoke **`gnome-control-center`** from the terminal prompt.  From there, you can select the keyboard app.

If you don't want to display the entry screen to system settings, pass ***keyboard*** as a parameter:

**`gnome-control-center keyboard`**.